"Probability of finding a system in a given state" in rigorous quantum mechanics
Feynman and Hibbs pg. 164 includes this paragraph:

The time development of a quantum-mechanical system can be pictured as follows. At an initial time $t_a$ the state is described by the wave function $\psi(x_a, t_a)$. At a later time to the original state will develop into the state $\phi(x_b, t_b)$.


At this later time suppose we ask the question: What is the probability of finding the system in the specific state $\chi(x_b, t_b)$? We know from the general principles developed in Chap. 5 that the probability of finding the system in this specified state is proportional to the square of the amplitude defined by $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi^*(x_b,t_b)\phi(x_b,t_b)dx_b.$$

What do they mean by saying "what is the probability of finding the system in the specific state $\chi(x_b,t_b)$?". As far as I understand, the system is in the state $\phi(x_b,t_b)$. When we make measurements, we do not measure states, we measure observable, what do they mean when they ask about measuring this observable?
Is what they mean: "On the assumption there exists an observable such that $\chi(x_b,t_b)$ is an eigenstate of the associated hermitian operator to that observeable, what is the probability of, under a measurement of this observable in the state $\phi(x_b,t_b)$, yielding the eigenvalue associated with $\chi(x_b,t_b)$"? If this is indeed what they mean, how do we know that all states $\chi(x_b,t_b)$ are eigenstates of some observable?

Well, for every vector $\psi$, the hermitian operator $P_\psi:=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ has $\psi$ as an eigenvector...

Please do not use images/screenshots for texts and quotes. Instead, type the relevant passage.

Thanks @TobiasFünke for the feedback. I have fixed the question.

As @TobiasFünke has pointed in the comments, mathematically we can always define a projection operator on a specific eigenstate, for example, $|\chi(x_b, t_b)\rangle\langle \chi(x_b, t_b)|$? and discuss eigenvalues of this operator.
However, the meaning is even more straightforward: when we measure an observable $A$, our measurements are the eigenvalues of these observable, which occur with probabilities $$|\langle \chi(x_b, t_b)|\phi(x_b, t_b)\rangle|^2=\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi^*(x_b,t_b)\phi(x_b,t_b)dx_b\right|^2.$$ We are thus effectively asking what is the probability of measuring specific value of the observable of interest?
In other words: what comes first is the observable, of which $\chi(x_b,t_b)$ is an eigenfunction, not the other way around.

Thank you for your insight. I agree we may construct a hermitian operator that has any state $\chi(x_b,t_b)$ as an eigenfunction, but does this implie that there exists an $\textit{observeable}$ with this as the associated operator. Indeed to each observeable corresponds a hermitian operator, but does this go both ways?

@Jack in the absence of superselection rules, we usually assume that indeed every hermitian operator corresponds to some observable (even if we don't know how to perform the corresponding measurement...)

@Jack it is an interesting question whether for an arbitrary function we can find corresponding observable. However, this is not what is meant in the text that you cite: they are already given an observable and project on its eigenfunction. They say something like: suppose we have an observable $A$ with an eigenfunction $\chi(x_b,t_b)$ corresponding to eigenvalue $A_b$, what is the probability of getting this value in the experiment? Btw, have you studied QM previously, from a more traditional textbook?

The crucial word here is "finding". It is rather misleading since it suggests, that the experiment only reveals a pre-existing value. However, this is not the case. The outcome of experiments is produces by the interaction between system and apparatus.
Let's stick to the standard rules of quantum mechanics for a moment. Assume that the statistics of an experiment are described by an operator $O$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, and corresponding (normalized) eigenstates $|\phi_i\rangle$. For simplicity assume that the eigenstates a not degenerated.
If the system's initial state is given by $|\Psi_\text{init}\rangle$, the experiment is causing the state of the system to change like
$$ |\Psi_\text{init}\rangle \mapsto \frac{1}{\mathcal N}|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i | \Psi_\text{init}\rangle$$
with probability $|\langle \Psi_\text{init} | \phi_i\rangle|^2$.
The experiment let's us know the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ corresponding to $\phi_i$. If we observe the value $\lambda = \lambda_i$ we can infere that the post measurement state is given up to phase by $|\phi_i\rangle$. In this sense we "find" the system to be in state $|\phi_i\rangle$. But this fact was created by the act performing the experiment.
There is experiment that could reveal the exact state before the experiment $|\psi_\text{init}\rangle$.
